# Round function in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Round function with float data type

```
DECLARE @Amt Float
DECLARE @Tax Float
DECLARE @Qty TINYINT
SET @Amt=70.96
SET @Tax=5.26
SET @Qty=1
SELECT ROUND((@Amt-@Tax)/@Qty, 2,1)
```

It gives me output as 65.69
but i want 65.70

Dont know why it's not working for float data type. If my datatype is decimal then it works but in my DB its float and i don't want to round off.

If i use Convert to decimal it works

```
SELECT ROUND((CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@Amt)-CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@Tax))/@Qty, 2,1)
```

It gives me Output as 65.700000.

Any other solution? plz help..

Comment: You should store amounts that need exact representation in the `DECIMAL` datatype, not the `FLOAT` datatype... You will keep running into problems with floats, whatever you do...

Comment: or use `money` if these are money quantities

Comment: Yes, first fix your database. Unless, further down the line, you want to be dealing with 0.000000003 (of whatever currency you're working with) due to accumulated rounding errors

Comment: As @TT says, but I want to add that the `1` in `ROUND` makes it truncate your expression, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is don't use `FLOAT` if you can avoid it, especially(!) for currency amounts.

The value `70.96 - 5.26 = 65.7` is exact to us, but it can't be stored exact in `FLOAT` because 70/100 has no exact binary representation, and you'll always get rounding artifacts.

Solution: use `DECIMAL` instead.

So like this:

```
DECLARE @Amt DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @Tax DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @Qty TINYINT
SET @Amt=70.96
SET @Tax=5.26
SET @Qty=1
SELECT (@Amt-@Tax)/@Qty
```

And yes, I did leave out the ROUND-call, because...

- It would not change the outcome;
- If the purpose was to get output with a certain amount of decimals, that shouldn't be done in the SQL backend but in the App/Web frontend because it is a presentation matter, which often means taking locale/regional/user-settings into account.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter of the ROUND function specifies whether the value should be rounded or truncated.

So you can use the following statement to get the expected result:

```
DECLARE @Amt Float
DECLARE @Tax Float
DECLARE @Qty TINYINT
SET @Amt=70.96
SET @Tax=5.26
SET @Qty=1
SELECT ROUND((@Amt-@Tax)/@Qty, 2,0)
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175003.aspx) for details

Answer (score 2):

Syntax:- `ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )`

Thaird parameter is "function" in `round` :- So for a value other than 0 is specified (in third parameter), numeric_expression is truncated Please see below for more.

From MSDN

> Function Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint,
>   smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0
>   (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is
>   specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

```
DECLARE @Amt Float
    DECLARE @Tax Float
    DECLARE @Qty TINYINT
    SET @Amt=70.96
    SET @Tax=5.26
    SET @Qty=1

    SELECT ROUND((@Amt-@Tax)/@Qty, 2,0)
```

For Second Query you have used, I have made few changes to it look below.

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@AMT)- 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@TAX)/@QTY),2)
```

The reason for again i have used convert is, Your expression has implicitly converted to decimal(15,6) data type.
For more check below queries

```
SELECT Sql_variant_property(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), @AMT) - CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), @TAX) / @QTY, 'BASETYPE'),
       Sql_variant_property(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), @AMT) - CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), @TAX) / @QTY, 'SCALE'),
       Sql_variant_property(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), @AMT) - CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), @TAX) / @QTY, 'PRECISION')
```

Comment: I don't want to round off. I just need to truncate the decimals after 2.

Comment: @ManojK You just need to keep 2nd parameter alone as 2. That will round it 2 decimals alone. And i have  Updated my post for your second approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use CAST

```
DECLARE @Amt Float
DECLARE @Tax Float
DECLARE @Qty TINYINT
SET @Amt=70.96
SET @Tax=5.26
SET @Qty=1


SELECT CAST((ROUND((@Amt-@Tax)/@Qty, 2,0)) as DECIMAL(10,2))
```